# Restore postgresql database from remote sql file

Tags: postgresql-9.2, remote

I would like to know if it's possible to restore a database from a remote sql file.
The problem:
- Working with PostgreSQL 9.2.4 
- I have an small remote server with 10GB left in storage
- I have a compressed sql file which is 2GB (decompressed, it takes 7GB)
- If I upload the zipped sql file to the server and extract it, I'm using 2+7GB, removing the zip file, it reminds 3GB free in the server, which is not enough for the database which needs 7GB.

Questions:
Is there any way to restore my remote database from a local sql file? 
If yes, how the command should look like?

Thank you!

Regards
Alejandro